# Fuel PHP - ORM - Has Many and Belongs To

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I'm having relationship issues (lol)... It's with the ORM.

I have two models 'Item' and 'Offer'. An Item can have many Offers - so Offer belongs to Item. But, an Offer also has one different item.

Here's my (simplified) Item Model:

```
class Model_Item extends \Orm\Model
{

  protected static $_belongs_to = array('user', 'offer');
  protected static $_has_many = array('offers');

  protected static $_properties = array(
    'id',
    'user_id',
  );

}
```

Here's my (simplified) Offer model:

```
class Model_Offer extends \Orm\Model
{
protected static $_belongs_to = array('item');
protected static $_has_one = array('item');

protected static $_properties = array(
  'id',
  'item_id',
  'owneditem_id', // <- THIS IS THE ITEM IT OWNS
  );
}
```

As you can see I need to be able to save the 'owning' item in the offer model, as well as an item that it 'owns', but I cannot redeclare item_id because it is already taken by the owner of the offer. How can I tell Fuel and the ORM that owneditem_id is an item object?

Answer (score 0):

I got it in the end!

Offer relationships:

```
protected static $_has_one = array(
        //(offered item)
        'offereditem' => array(
            'key_from' => 'offereditem_id',
            'model_to' => 'Model_Item',
      'key_to' => 'id',
      'cascade_save' => true,
      'cascade_delete' => false,
        )
    );
```

and item model relationships:

protected static $_belongs_to = array('user', 'item');
protected static $_has_many = array('offers');

with migrations:

```
//Add OfferedItem to Offers Migration
oil generate migration add_offereditem_to_offers offereditem:int

//Rename OfferedItem to OfferedItem_ID in Offers Migration
oil generate migration rename_field_offereditem_to_offereditem_id_in_offers
```

Answer (score 0):

in fuel/app/migration modify your create_Offers.php

```
public function up()
{
    \DBUtil::create_table('offers', array(
        'id' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'auto_increment' 
    ), array('id'),false, 'InnoDB', 'utf8_general_ci',
array(
    array(
        'constraint' => 'offers_items',
        'key' => 'offer_id',
        'reference' => array(
            'table' => 'items',
            'column' => 'id',
        ),
        'on_update' => 'CASCADE',
        'on_delete' => 'RESTRICT'
    ))););
}
```